# nUnit Integration test weird interaction with other test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a bunch of tests which execute basically a file being moved around. 
At the end I check if the file exists in the target directory.

I have 8 such tests which all look the same except for some minor differences.

One of the tests fails when run together with one specific other test (we call it: fTest). I found the culprit codeline and it is this simple assert running in a suceeding test (sTest). When I comment the Assert line, fTest does no longer fail.

```
var exists = File.Exists(@"\\?\" + destFullPath);
Assert.AreEqual(true, exists);
```

Even when I remove the first line and change the second line to `Assert.AreEqual(true, true)` the fTest still fails. Only commenting it out works.

This is some really weird behavior and I have absolutely no clue what is going on. How can one test affect the other?

EDIT: I just copied the sTest, deleted the original and renamed the copy to "TEST()" and now fTest works. What the f*?

Comment: what exactly is the other test doing?  is it possible that the order the tests are run could cause a problem?

Comment: Please provide the code for both of your tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Since these are integration tests there was one test which needed to run first. I added the order:1 attribute and now it works.